# How to center headers when spliting one table column into sub-columns with merged header?

Tags: tables, header-footer, multicolumn, multirow, split

I made this table with merged headers and I can't find out why I don't get to align (vertically) the terms "IL Results" and "Random testsets". My code may look a bit confusing because there are many columns splits and math texts, but I brought it below. Maybe someone has a suggestion.

Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Model Results I}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{
\textbf{{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
\\IL\\Results\end{tabular}}}}}&

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{
\textbf{{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
\\Random\\testset\end{tabular}}}
}}&

\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Journey Model}}\\
\cline{3-7}

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & &
\textbf{D003}&
\textbf{D004}&
\textbf{D003}&
\textbf{D003}&
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & &
\textbf{$\mathbf{3\phi}$}&
\textbf{$\mathbf{3\phi}$}&
\textbf{$\mathbf{1\phi}$}&
\textbf{$\mathbf{2\phi}$}& \\ \hline


\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{D003}  & 2 & 7 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 19\\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{D004}  & 11 & 3 & 1 & 12 & 5 & 21\\ \hline 


\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Other IL} & 101 & 89 & 64 & 75 & 64  & 292\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\begin{scriptsize}All\end{scriptsize}\\\begin{scriptsize}Inspections\end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}} & 114 & 99 & 67 & 94 & 72 & 332\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \begin{scriptsize}General \end{scriptsize}\\ \begin{scriptsize}Success Rate \end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}}&
11.4\%&
\begin{scriptsize}10.1\%\end{scriptsize} & \begin{scriptsize}4.5\%\end{scriptsize} & \begin{scriptsize}20.2\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}11.1\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}12.0\%\end{scriptsize}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\begin{scriptsize}D003\end{scriptsize}\\ \begin{scriptsize}Success Rate \end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}}
&1.8\%&
\begin{scriptsize}7.1\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}3.0\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}7.4\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}4.2\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}5.7\%\end{scriptsize}\\ \hline

%#### END TABLE
\end{tabular}
\label{tab-results}
\end{center}
\end{table}
%#### END TABLE

\end{document}
```

Comment: was the answer helpful -- if so please accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to have trial and error --instead of 3 rows try 2.5 or 2.4 rows in multirow

```
{\multirow{2.5}{*}{\textbf{IL Results}}}
```

Suggest removing scriptsize and tabular in between the main tabular

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Model Results I}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} \toprule
{\multirow{2.5}{*}{\textbf{IL Results}}}&{\multirow{2.5}{*}{\textbf{Random testset}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Journey Model}}\\ \cline{3-7}
 & &\textbf{D003}&\textbf{D004}&\textbf{D003}&\textbf{D003}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\ 

& &\textbf{$\mathbf{3\phi}$}&\textbf{$\mathbf{3\phi}$}&\textbf{$\mathbf{1\phi}$}&\textbf{$\mathbf{2\phi}$}& \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{D003}  & 2 & 7 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 19\\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{c}{D004}  & 11 & 3 & 1 & 12 & 5 & 21\\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{c}{Other IL} & 101 & 89 & 64 & 75 & 64  & 292\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\begin{scriptsize}All\end{scriptsize}\\\begin{scriptsize}Inspections\end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}} & 114 & 99 & 67 & 94 & 72 & 332\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \begin{scriptsize}General \end{scriptsize}\\ \begin{scriptsize}Success Rate \end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}}&
11.4\%&
\begin{scriptsize}10.1\%\end{scriptsize} & \begin{scriptsize}4.5\%\end{scriptsize} & \begin{scriptsize}20.2\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}11.1\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}12.0\%\end{scriptsize}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\begin{scriptsize}D003\end{scriptsize}\\ \begin{scriptsize}Success Rate \end{scriptsize}\end{tabular}}
&1.8\%&
\begin{scriptsize}7.1\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}3.0\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}7.4\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}4.2\% \end{scriptsize}& \begin{scriptsize}5.7\%\end{scriptsize}\\ \bottomrule

%#### END TABLE
\end{tabular}
\label{tab-results}
\end{center}
\end{table}
%#### END TABLE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot :D

About scriptsize and tabular, it's all about little space I have in my document to fit my table haha